# Finding an algorithm for merging sorted list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The question goes as follows : 
There are k sorted lists of length n/k (we assume that k divides n).
I need to find an algorithm that merge those lists into one list of length n 
with running time complexity O(k + nlogk).

I was thinking of merging the lists by couples , 
than merge the merged lists again by couples, and so on and I stop when I get to a one sorted list of length n.

When I calculated the time complexity of my algorithm I got O(nlogk) which is batter than the time needed.

I was wondering if my way is wrong. 
Thanks for helping !

Comment: explain how you got that result.

Comment: In each iteration it takes O(n) to merge the lists, and we have log k iterations. @KarolyHorvath

Comment: Assuming k <= n (which will always be the case), the complexity is equivalent to O(nlogk)

Comment: O(n log k) sounds right to me. Since this is smaller, it is also O(k + n log k). So I would say task solved.

Comment: Well, thanks i taught i was missing something.

Comment: In your analysis, do you always estimate the merging of two lists by `O(n)`?

Comment: @tobias_k im merging the lists by couples, after each iteration there are half lists left.

Comment: @Codor yes, each iteration takes O(n).

Comment: @Liad I see, I thought with "iteration" you meant merging one pair of lists, but apparently you meant merging half the lists. Yes, then it seems to make sense. Also, then the O(n) makes sense, since you will touch each element once. So O(nlogk) seems plausible.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; it may take `O(n)` to merge `2` lists, but in the first iteration, you perform `k/2` merges. Or is the argument that the terms `k/2`, `k/4`, `k/8` sum up to `2k = O(k)`?

Comment: @Codor See my comment. With one "iteration", OP meant merging all the current lists to half that number. I.e. if you start with 8 lists, you merge those to 4 in the first iteration, to 2 in the second, and to 1 in the last. In each iteration you have to look at all n elements, and there are logk iterations, thus O(nlogk). The +k probably comes from selecting the total of k-1 pairs for merging.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the clarification, it was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is fine.

When it's given that k<=n, and k>=1, then O(n log k) = O(k + n log k). Both of these are implied by the statement that "we assume that k divides n", so your results are what they're supposed to be.

If we relax those conditions, then we have to consider the cases where k>n, and some of those k lists are *empty*.  Then you have to worry about the time taken to merge all those empty lists, and your algorithm takes O(k + n log k) time.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that  O(nlogk) is O(k + nlogk) because k <= n as mentioned by @MattTimernans. It is easy to get O(k + nlogk) by using heap. First we build the heap of the all first element of each list which takes O(k). Then, we pop an element and push a new element back into the heap. Continuing to do it N time, we will have a sorting list by merging all the list in O(k + nlogk)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, it is possible to achieve a running time of

```
O(k^2*(n/k)) = O(kn)
```

by the following idea. Suppose the lists are sorted in nondecreasing order. Iterate until all lists are empty. In each iteration, use `k` steps to determine for which list the first element is minimum with respect to all the first elements of the lists. Remove the element from the list and append it to the result.

Comment: But O(nk) is more than the required O(k+nlogk).